# How to remove one element from dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, unity-game-engine

I have dictionary like this

```
private Dictionary<BasePlayer, List<ulong>> findit = new Dictionary<BasePlayer, List<ulong>>();
```

and add elements to it using

```
findit[player].Add(targetid); 
findit[player].Add(friendid);
```

on another section

```
if (findit.ContainsKey(player))
findit.Remove(player);
```

but using findit.Remove(player) it's removed all elements "targetid and friendid"

how i can remove only targetid from findit dictionary ?

Comment: `findit[player].Remove(targetid);`?

Comment: You say, you want to remove element from dictionary, but actually you want to remove an element from the list, which is a value in the dictionary. `findit[player].Remove(targetid)`;

Comment: yes is it, thank you, another question, how i can remove first entry from findit[player] without specfying the value, this right or wrong ? findit[player].Remove(0);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That you need is something like this:

```
if (findit.ContainsKey(player))
{
     findit[player].Remove(targetid);
}
```

Using `findit.Remove(player)` you remove the key value pair from the dictionary with key `player`. You don't need this, based on your post. You just want to remove one entry from the value (which is a list in your case) associated with this key.

**Update**

If you just want to remove the first item in the list associated with the player, you could just use list's method `RemoveAt` passing as an argument the 0, since you want to remove the first item.

Comment: thank you, another question, how i can remove first entry from findit[player] without specfying the value, somthing like this findit[player].Remove([0]);

Comment: @MisterBrooks [`findit[player].RemoveAt(0);`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeat?view=netframework-4.7.2)